# Function keys do not register in system

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, function-keys

I have an Asus Zephyrus S laptop (GX502GW), and I am aware that support won't be great because it has newer hardware.
Currently, I have Kubuntu 20.04 installed alongside Win 10 and I have been setting it up as my workstation. This problem is not present with Windows.

I noticed that around half of the fn keys are completely ignored by the system. I have used `showkey` with a TTY console to identify that these keys do not do anything:

- Fan speed
- Screen off
- Brightness Down
- Brightness up
- KB Brightness Down
- KB Brightness Up
- KB Profile Previous (meant for backlight profile)
- KB Profile Next (Meant for backlight profile)
- Touchpad Disable/Enable
- Sleep
- Airplane mode
- Microphone mute
- custom Asus ROG Key (I am aware the ROG software is windows-only. I would like to manually keybind this.)

Whenever I press one of those keys I can see it show up with showkey. With the unresponsive backlight keys, or the sleep/touchpad/airplane-mode keys, I don't see anything in showkey.

I've tried modifying my grub file with different vendor boot profiles, none seemed to work.

How can I go about getting the keys properly mapped? I am familiar with the Keyboard subsystem on Windows but not so much with Linux. I don't mind manually adding in the missing keys for this device and providing the mapping to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Many/Most [Multimedia Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_control_symbols) aren't set up by default to perform any action.  There are many posts that help explain a few different ways to identify and set up commands or scripts to perform when these keys are pressed.

I've found that [`xbindkeys_config`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xbindkeys-config), the GUI for `xbindkeys`, is one of the easiest ways to bind keys.  To have `xbindkeys` start with your Desktop Manager, add `xbindkeys` to your `~/.xinitrc` file.  More detailed instructions can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys).

---

If these keys aren't showing up as keycodes, you can use `udev` or `evtest` to find the scancode, and map it to the correct keycode.  You can create custom hwdb entries for udev to correct this problem.  [Map scancodes to keycodes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes).

The wiki describes creating `.hwdb` files, and restarting `udev`:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/10-my-modifiers.hwdb

evdev:input:b0003v05AFp8277* # was tested on Kensington Slim Type USB (with old ABI)
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70039=leftalt  # bind capslock to leftalt
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e2=leftctrl # bind leftalt to leftctrl

evdev:atkbd:dmi:*            # built-in keyboard: match all AT keyboards for now
 KEYBOARD_KEY_3a=leftalt     # bind capslock to leftalt
 KEYBOARD_KEY_38=leftctrl    # bind leftalt to leftctrl

$ sudo systemd-hwdb update
```

**This question, and these details are described in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/130762/10805) wonderful answer from Unix & Linux**.  These details were very useful for me with a fully programmable keyboard, when I added new HID/scancodes, otherwise they wouldn't be detected properly.

There is also a way to re-query the device for these details, which is easier when it works properly, but I'm at a loss as to where my notes on this topic are located.

Comment: Hm. It seems that in my case the events are simply not being sent by the Kernel. I can see the correct device with evtest, but it fails to generate any events for the extended device. I have no idea how to patch the kernel, how can I proceed further? Should I create a ticket on the Debian base kernel? I'll say it now, I have no idea how to patch the kernel.